# When updating the TestFlight SDK do you need to delete the old version?

Tags: objective-c, testflight

How do you install a new TestFlight SDK if you have an older version installed? do you delete the old sdk folder from your project before installing the new one? or do you just install the old one over the top? and how does that effect the libTestFlight.a file?

Comment: You really should take a look at CocoaPods. I use it for all the frameworks I use in projects. It manages them brilliantly. The TestFlightSDK is on there too. So to update it you just run `pod update` in Terminal. Everyone should be using it. http://www.cocoapods.org

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm compelled to add that it is your _opinion_ to use CocoaPods. I use git submodules for the Testflight SDK in my projects instead of CocoaPods; which is just _my opinion_.

Comment: @Abizern And the award for pointless comment of the day goes to... Of course it's my opinion... I don't even know how to respond to that. Completely baffled by that comment.

Comment: "You really should…" I know it's your opinion - just reminding the OP that it is. No need to get upset about it.

Comment: "You really should... take a look at Cocoapods" (please don't take part of a sentence out of context). I'm not telling him to use it. I'm suggesting he take a look at it as I find it incredibly useful. It makes things like using external frameworks much easier for me. I'm not upset, just baffled.

Answer (score 2):

If your are adding the TestFlight source to your project it will build the library, so just overwriting the source files is enough, as is deleting and re-adding them. As long as you do it cleanly and don't leave old files hanging around as well as the new ones it makes no difference.

Use CocoaPods / Git submodules / Any other method to do this as you choose.

Comment: Well the old folder is 1.2.4 and the new one is 2.0, so it will create a new folder I presume, even though the contents are the same? So maybe it's better to just delete the old 1.2.4 folder and add the 2.0 one?

Comment: The name of the folder isn't important as long as it is in Xcode. It does make a difference to your source management system, though. Either way, just make sure that you are using the sources from the correct version.

Comment: Can you tell me please how can I add TestFlight to my objective-c project using pod? What should I write in the podFile?

Comment: You don't do this anymore. TestFlight is now part of Apple.